# running on a mongo collection and change array field to be distinct

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb

I have a collection in my mongodb, and this collection have a field called "errors" which is an array.

this array pushed allot of errors and I want to distinct it. For example:

```
"errors" : [
        {
            "when" : ISODate("2018-02-06T18:23:42.315Z"),
            "err" : "No document existing"
        },
        {
            "when" : ISODate("2018-02-06T18:53:48.396Z"),
            "err" : "No document existing"
        },
        {
            "when" : ISODate("2018-02-06T19:23:50.118Z"),
            "err" : "No document existing"
        },
        {
            "when" : ISODate("2018-02-06T19:53:52.205Z"),
            "err" : "Conversion Error - ABC"
        },
        {
            "when" : ISODate("2018-02-06T20:23:53.838Z"),
            "err" : "Conversion Error - ABC"
        },
        {
            "when" : ISODate("2018-02-06T20:53:55.615Z"),
            "err" : "Conversion Error - DFL"
        },
        {
            "when" : ISODate("2018-02-06T21:23:57.826Z"),
            "err" : "Conversion Error - DFL"
        },
        {
            "when" : ISODate("2018-02-06T22:54:07.410Z"),
            "err" : "Conversion Error - DFL"
        }
    ]
```

above you can see errors array of certain document, I would want to make it:

```
"errors" : [
        {
            "when" : ISODate("2018-02-06T18:23:42.315Z"),
            "err" : "No document existing"
        }
        {
            "when" : ISODate("2018-02-06T20:23:53.838Z"),
            "err" : "Conversion Error - ABC"
        }
        {
            "when" : ISODate("2018-02-06T22:54:07.410Z"),
            "err" : "Conversion Error - DFL"
        }
    ]
```

so I want to run a script that will do it, so I came up with something like:

```
db.myCollection.find({}).forEach(it => {

    var errs = new Set(it.errors.map(x => x.err))

    db. myCollection.findOneAndUpdate({_id: it._id}, {$set: {errors: errs}})

});
```

but this way im losing my "when"...and another challenge is that the real error array is much bigger, can have even 50K elements inside..

any solutions for this issue?

thanks!

Comment: In "distincting" it,  do you want to take the earliest "when", the latest "when", or all the "when"?   Also:   Do you actually want to update the data or just query it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
db.foo.aggregate([
{$unwind: "$errors"},
{$group: {_id: "$errors.err", when: {$FUNC: "$errors.when"} }}
   ]);
```

Where `FUNC` can be `first`, `last`, or `push`.   `push` will give you all the `when`.   NOTE: `first` and `last` will do the expected thing if the errors array is *already* in sorted order.   If not, you will have to sort thusly:

```
db.foo.aggregate([
{$unwind: "$errors"},
{$sort: {"errors.when":1} },
{$group: {_id: "$errors.err", when: {$FUNC: "$errors.when"} }}
   ]);
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use aggregate...

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([{
$group: {
    _id: '$err',
    "when": {
        $first: "$when"
    },
    "err": {
        $first: "$err"
    }
}
}])
```

which should give you `distinct` documents grouped by the error

Comment: That pipeline does not produce a result.